js throws Illegal invocation while importing a package dynamically
next: 12.3.2
node: 20.11.1
react: 17.0.2
core-js: 3.29.0
webpack: 5.76.0
  useEffect(function () {
    loadAuthFill();
  }, []);
  const loadAuthFill = async () => {
    appovalRef.current = await import('@ctrip/corp-bizComp-authprocess/dist/static/authProcess.js');
  };

when i tried to import the js dynamically, it throws a runtime error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at Object.registerExportsForReactRefresh (helpers.js:52:1)
    at eval (dom-token-list-prototype.js:7:1)
    at eval (dom-token-list-prototype.js:7:1)
    at ./node_modules/core-js/internals/dom-token-list-prototype.js (node_modules_ctrip_corp-bizComp-authprocess_dist_static_authProcess_js.js:7993:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:683:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:338:21)
    at eval (web.dom-collections.for-each.js:3:29)
    at ./node_modules/core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each.js (node_modules_ctrip_corp-bizComp-authprocess_dist_static_authProcess_js.js:12540:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:683:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:338:21)
    at eval (index.js:243:1)
    at ./node_modules/core-js/stable/index.js (node_modules_ctrip_corp-bizComp-authprocess_dist_static_authProcess_js.js:12737:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:683:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:338:21)
    at eval (authProcess.js:1:1)
    at ./node_modules/@ctrip/corp-bizComp-authprocess/dist/static/authProcess.js (node_modules_ctrip_corp-bizComp-authprocess_dist_static_authProcess_js.js:6134:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:683:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:37:33)
    at Function.fn (webpack.js?ts=1725937482870:338:21)
    at async loadAuthFill (index.tsx:86:26)

error
the package which was about to import exports a object like this:
enter image description here

I tried to import the package with dynamic api, but it didn't work out like I expected. I expect
that the package returns a object with Init, Submit function in the object

